# About the acquisition of mass by particles

Tags: cosmology

In particle accelerators, ephemeral particles are produced by reactions between particles, as sufficiently high energies are reached. 
 In the early life stages of the universe there were very high energies, what forbids them to exist?

Comment: All these ephemeral particles live only a very, very short time.

Comment: definition of ephemeral https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ephemeral

Answer (score 1):

nothing forbade those particles to exist at very early times. in fact the universe we inhabit is the product of the progressive decays of those primordial particles into the most stable forms available to them, and their interactions with photons along the way.

This is why you can think of a particle accelerator as a time machine, which reproduces (in a very tiny space and for a vanishingly short time) the conditions present in the very early universe.

Comment: What about the Higgs field? It did not exist during a very early time when the high energy particles at that time did not yet have mass. Since the Higgs field exists now, the properties of a particle accelerated in an accelerator is not exactly the same as it was at this earliest time period.

Comment: @buzz, we can make the higgs (just barely) in our most powerful accelerators today.